# Neo4j : loadByProperty is loading the other objects that doesn't belong to the node

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

my structure is as follows:

a company -> having set of users -> each user is having set of policies -> each policy is for a company.

sample graph structure :

```
       u1 <- c1 -> u2 
       p1 -> c1
       u1 -> p1
```

company(c1) is having two users (u1, u2) and a policy(p1) belongs lo company(c1). "u1" has taken the policy(p1). "u2" has no policy.

When i'm trying to load the u2 by "loadByProperty" method, expected should be User2 object and the corresponding Company(c1).

But, the policy(p1) is also loading and setting to "u2" object.

Class Structure;

```
Company{
   Stirng companyName;
   @Relationship(type = "hasUsers", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
   List<User> users;
}

User{
   Stirng userName;
   @Relationship(type = "hasPolicy", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
   List<Policy> policies;
}

Policy{
   String policyName;
   @Relationship(type = "forCompany", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
   Company company;
}
```

Method for retrieving User:

```
 public User getUser(String userName) { 
    Property<String, Object> properties = new Property<String, Object("userName", userName); 
    Set<User> users = (Set<User>) session.loadByProperty(User.class, properties); 
    if (users != null && !users.isEmpty()) 
        for (User user : users) 
            return user; 
   return null; 
 }
```

Using SDN 4 (mile stone version).

Any suggestions? Thanks is advance.

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: public User getUser(String userName) {                                                    
                Property<String, Object> properties = new Property<String, Object>("userName", userName);
  Set<User> users = (Set<User>) session.loadByProperty(User.class, properties);
  if (users != null && !users.isEmpty())
   for (User user : users)
    return user;
  return null;
 }

Comment: Please also share the User/Company/Policy classes

Comment: updated description..Please see above

Comment: Unable to reproduce this with the code shared. Please log an issue at http://jira.spring.io with a test. Please upgrade to use 4.0.0.RC1 - Property is no longer available, it's called Filter now.

Comment: Thakns..i'll upgrade to 4.0.0.RC1 and get back to you.

Comment: Can you please give an overview on Property/Filter.

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this? Please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways in which you can load an entity by property value.

**Neo4jOperations**

Use `loadByProperty` or `loadAllByProperty`

**Derived finders (repositories only)**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {

User findByName(String name); 

}
```

SDN will use the metadata info to translate this into a Cypher query.

**@Query (repositories only)**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {

   @Query("MATCH (user:User{name:{0}}) RETURN user")
   User findUserByName(String name);

}
```

**Session**

Use any of the `loadAll` methods which accept a `Filter`.
Example:

```
session.loadAll(Person.class, new Filter("firstName", "John"))
```